# nodejs fs.readFile() or data.toString() can not deal with Chinese.'utf-8' is useless

Tags: node.js, utf-8

```
var fs = require("fs");
console.log("Hello World");
fs.readFile('../../input.txt','utf-8',function (err,data){
    if(err){
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(data.toString()+'\n');
});
console.log('天气不错\n');
```

why I can not print right Chinese even with UTF-8
[console cant not print Chinese in 'input.txt'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXwCm.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuRY8.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXwCm.png)

Comment: What encoding was `input.txt` saved to disk with? The encoding used then is what's needed to read the file and convert it into a string value in your script. (Note: The encodings that Node supports are [listed in the documentation for `Buffer`s](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings).)

Comment: perhaps the console in webstrom is using the system file encoding, which is case WINDOWS-1252

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-iconv

Comment: @bluelovers you should explain you comment. this not csdn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just forget save input.txt file in utf-8 by note